# jQuery refreshing a link after clicked

Tags: jquery

will do my best to explain. Very new to jQuery so hope makes sense.

I am using a Favourites add-on for Expression Engine that allows me to mark an entry as a favourite, or a private favourite. (one or the other) so I'm utilising the private function as a mean to bookmark.
You mark items as favourites by means of a hyperlink which registers it when clicked and similarly when removing.

I am displaying these links and making them show/hide the other links with the help of jQuery.

Heres is my current jQuery code:

```
// favourites adding and removing
jQuery(function(jQuery) { // Shorthand for jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('a.mark').live('click', function() {
        var self = this;
        jQuery.get(self.href, {theID: self.id.substring(3)}, function(data) {
              jQuery(self).html('A Favorite').toggleClass('mark marked').
                    closest('li').prevAll('li:has(a.bookmarks)').hide(300);
        });
        return false;
  });
  jQuery('a.marked').live('mouseover', function() {
        jQuery(this).html('Remove Favourite');
  }).live('mouseout', function() {
        jQuery(this).html('A Favourite');
  }).live('click', function() {
        var self = this;
        jQuery.get(self.href, {theID: self.id.substring(3)}, function(data) {
              jQuery(self).html('Save as a Favourite').toggleClass('marked mark').
                    closest('li').prevAll('li:has(a.bookmarks)').show(300);
        });
        return false;
  });
});

// bookmarks adding and removing
jQuery(function(jQuery) { // Shorthand for jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('a.bookmarks').live('click', function() {
        var self = this;
        jQuery.get(self.href, {theID: self.id.substring(3)}, function(data) {
              jQuery(self).html('A Bookmark').toggleClass('bookmark bookmarks').
               closest('li').nextAll('li:has(a.mark)').hide(300); // Or .hide(300);
        });
        return false;
  });
  jQuery('a.bookmark').live('mouseover', function() {
        jQuery(this).html('Remove Bookmark');
  }).live('mouseout', function() {
        jQuery(this).html('A Bookmark');
  }).live('click', function() {
        var self = this;
        jQuery.get(self.href, {theID: self.id.substring(3)}, function(data) {
              jQuery(self).html('Save as a Bookmark').toggleClass('bookmark bookmarks').
                    closest('li').nextAll('li:has(a.mark)').show(300); // Or .hide(300);
        });
        return false;
  });
});
```

Now this works almost exactly as it should do, except I have to refresh the page once a "add" link is clicked, in order for it to generate the correct delete links.

The type of behaviour I need is basically to refresh the section once the link has been clicked, making everything register as if the page had been refreshed.

Does that make sense? i hope so! Thanks!

Comment: In most setups `$()` is the same as `jQuery()`.  Don't know if you knew that, but it sure makes it easier to type out.

Comment: If you're worried about conflicting with another framework that uses "$" you can still start your function(s) with `jQuery(function($)` and everything INSIDE can at least safely use the `$` jQuery object shorthand.

Comment: @GregPettit: True.  Basically, there isn't usually a good reason to have to type it out every time.

Comment: The unorthodox style just makes the code hard to read. Also, there's no need to redeclare `this` to `self`. The only time you need to cache `this` is when you're wrapping it up as an object. `var jqThis = $(this)` for example.

Comment: Well this code was suggested in jQuery Forums, I'm all open to a suggestion of something better. Like I said I'm new to this, and not really sure exactly how to achieve what I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right just thought i'd finish this one up. Finally got it working!

The jist of it is....

In order to change the href as well as the class, I had to manually add a delete link to my code

```
// favourites adding and removing
jQuery(function (jQuery) {
jQuery('a.fav_me').live('click', function () {
    var self = this;
    jQuery.get(self.href, {
        theID: self.id.substring(3)
    }, function (data) {
        jQuery(self).html('A Favourite').toggleClass('fav_me fav_delete');
    });
    return false;
});
jQuery('a.fav_delete').live('mouseover', function () {
    var entryID = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
    jQuery(this).html('Remove Favourite').attr('href',     'http://domain.com/forms/favourite-add/' + entryID + '/delete/');
}).live('mouseout', function () {
    jQuery(this).html('A Favourite');
}).live('click', function () {
    var entryID = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
    var self = this;
    jQuery.get(self.href, {
        theID: self.id.substring(3)
    }, function (data) {
        jQuery(self).html('Save as a Favourite').toggleClass('fav_delete fav_me').attr('href', 'http://domain.com/forms/favourite-add/' + entryID);
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

and then my template looked like this...

```
{if not_saved}
                        <li><a class="fav_me" id="{entry_id}" href="{path=forms/favourite-add}/{entry_id}" rel="{entry_id}">Save as a Favourite</a></li>
                        {/if}<!--not saved-->
                        {if saved}
                        <li><a class="fav_delete" id="{entry_id}" href="{path=forms/favourite-add}/{entry_id}/delete/" rel="{entry_id}" >A Favourite</a></li>
                        {/if}
```

Thats what I had to put in order to get it to work. I also decided against having fav and bookmarks, so i then had no need to show or hide the other bookmark/fav. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems ok when I put it in a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/59e4p/1/

I changed the link so that it changes to "Remove Favourite/Bookmark" when the update completes, because it will change to "A Favourite/Bookmark" when you mouseout.  Other than that, it seems ok.

I'm not entirely sure about the behavior you want with hiding/showing other `li`s that contain bookmarks.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Sorry its hard to explain, the actual links and the text "change" fine, however they do not actually change the target of the link once its clicked. The link to add and remove is not the same. The link to remove has /delete on the end of the url, but this is not showing until the page is refreshed. Am I making sense? :)

Comment: just edited the fiddle to show..

http://jsfiddle.net/59e4p/2/

watch how when you click the link, the behaviour runs but the target url does not change until its refreshed.

Comment: I don't see anything in the code that would add a /delete to the end. On hover, all you're doing is changing the class and HTML. This would be an ideal time to modify the href. However, it could wait until click. But the click handler also does not modify the URL.

Comment: @shorn: As Greg pointed out, you need code that will add and remove `/delete`.  You are probably generating this in the backend, which is why you get the correct info when you refresh.  Unless you load that code from the server again, you won't see an update.  Is your `.get()` supposed to be returning the html for the links again?  If so, you need to use the `data`, by inserting it into your DOM, replacing the old link.  If you don't do that, you need to change the links with jQuery, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/59e4p/7/

Comment: So a simple question is: what is `.get(self.href, {theID: ...` supposed to return?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the responses. Sorry for the delay in getting back, but called away for work!

Anyhow, I'm afraid you've lost me! Bit out of my depth with this one I think! I tried out your code from the fiddle, but its not working in my site at all, and stops the rest of the jQuery from working. ?

Comment: Just thinking out loud... is there anyway to refresh the div that the links are in. I think this might need to be done, as my site template needs to run an sql query in order to determine if its a private or public favourite, so at the moment everything works as it should provided I refresh the page after I click any link. If i could refresh the div after each click then that would achieve everything that I want it to do.

Comment: The problem is that the data needs to come from the server.  When you call `.get('/fav/url/delete'...)`, what does the server return?

Comment: Ok, the actual add-on that I am using adds an entry to that users favourites.
When the url is clicked to add a favourite it redirects the user to another template that contains a template tag from the add-on. This template tag does whatever it needs to to log that entry as a favourite, and then outputs a relevant success/error message. The idea of doing it via jQuery was to negate the need to have to visit another page just to get the favourite added/removed.

Comment: The links in the fiddle are just examples, the actual links are something like
{site_url}forms/bookmark-add/{entry_id} - to add an entry and
{site_url}forms/bookmark-add/{entry_id}/delete - to delete it.

forms/bookmark-add/ being the template that contains the code to add/delete.

Not sure if this is making sense?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/59e4p/21/

This is the actual code that I am using (Although my template does include some IF conditionals to tell whether or not an entry has been saved. Therefore if it has been favourited/bookmarked, you would only see the second link for each.

Using that code, everything works except being able to save as a fav and then immediately delete again without refreshing the page. (obviously the refresh of the page runs the IF conditional)

Not sure if this is helpful or not?